# Cannot access Headless Raspberry pi due to wifi

Tags: raspbian, headless

So I have a long time RPi running headless and SSH works fine for like a few months now. The problem is: one day, (and I apologize in advance for having so little information) I cannot ssh into the RPi anymore, no WiFi settings were changed and I even verified that the raspberry pi's IP stayed the same.

I checked the router, and it says the raspberry pi was offline, but as you will imagine, how can I connect it back to Wifi when I can't SSH into it?. I wonder how I can connect the raspberry pi back to wifi again.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your RPi is running; i.e. is the "red light" illuminated? If so, have you tried to power cycle (pull the power connector, then re-insert?

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed it is running, is there a way to reconnect to Wifi without reinstalling the whole operating system? I do not have serial cables to manually connect to it.

Comment: Did you power-cycle? (pull USB/power plug, count to 10, re-insert plug to power up)

Answer (score 1):

If SSH is not working you are really limited:

1. Check all addresses on the LAN - it may be somewhere new.
2. Does VNC work?
3. Physical access with a keyboard / monitor?
4. Serial port access via GPIO?
5. Any other application still running that a network search will show (shared files / MQTT etc)?

If they fail it's a reset / power cycle to see if it comes back.  If not it's worth using a new SD card and check the old one rather than just retrying the reset.

On-going, this script [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=239730#p1465991) (credit goes to Dougie Lawson) may help once you are up and running.

Comment: Nothing works because the raspberry PI is headless therefore I cannot physically access it and I cannot use VNC because its disconnected from the Wifi.

Comment: If you are 100% sure it's not on the LAN than it's a reset.